# Unable to find symbol 'Components'

Tags: visual-studio, reference, gruntjs, typescript, grunt-ts

I've got 3 modules in 3 separate folders, each (test-wise) with one file:

- components/pagedList.ts
- directives/testDirective.ts
- entity1/entity1.ts

Which approx. look like this

```
// pagedList.ts
module App.Components {
    export interface IPagedList<T> {
        ...
    }
}

// testDirective.ts
module App.Directives {
    export class TestDirective {
        ...
    }
}

// entity1.ts
module App.Entity1 {
    export interface IEntity1 {
        ...
    }
}
```

When I try to reference them as dependencies, it works for all except module `App.Components`. Both *Intellisense* (Visual Studio) as well as my *typescript grunt* task are `unable to find symbol 'App.Components'`. Is this a <strike>reserved keyword</strike> or something? **Edit**: Tried renaming and relocating, still not working though.

```
var dependencies = [
    "ui.router", 
    "ui.bootstrap",
    Components, // Unable to find symbol 'Components'
    Directives,
    Entity1,
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because `App.Components` is what's called an *uninstantiated module*. Because there is only an interface in it, the compiler only creates a symbol in the type namespace, and doesn't create any value at runtime.

Once `Components` has a class, var, or instantiated module in it, you'll see that error go away. You can put in a dummy non-exported var in here if needed in the meantime.